# how to sort firestore data in html bootstrap DataTable through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I fetch data of cloud storage from firebase and it is success also but it is not sorting.
when i take static data then it is complete working,
i can't understand where is my mistake,
i try more times to solve this but can't solve,
please someone help me..

thank you in advance  :)

```
    <script>
      
       $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myTable1').DataTable();
        } );

        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "",
            authDomain: "",
            databaseURL: "",
            projectId: "",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: "",
            appId: "",
            measurementId: ""
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        firebase.analytics();
        const booksRef = firebase.firestore().collection("JSDATA");
         booksRef.get().then(function (querySnapshot){
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                   document.getElementById("myTable1").innerHTML += "<tbody> <tr> <td>" + doc.data().Email  + "</td> <td>" +  doc.data().Password + "</td> </tr> </tbody>"                
                    console.log(doc.data().Email);
                });
            });
       
 
        console.log("hii");
        booksRef.get().then((snapshot) => {
            const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
              id: doc.id,
              ...doc.data(),
            }));
            console.log("All data in 'books' collection", data);
            // const userdata = document.querySelector("#myTable1");
           
            // [ { id: 'glMeZvPpTN1Ah31sKcnj', title: 'The Great Gatsby' } ] 
          });
    </script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Frestore Data</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>FireStore Data</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="myTable1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <!-- <th class="th-sm" scope="col">Sr.No</th> -->
                    <th class="th-sm" scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th class="th-sm" scope="col">Password</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <!-- <td></td> -->
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

in this image the data is of firestore it is not sorting..

[image]

with Static Data it is running perfect..

[image]

Comment: On which field you want to sort? Email?

Comment: not any single field i want to sort all fields like https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now It is Working through below code..

Thank you so much..

```js
 var firebaseConfig = {
           apiKey: "",
            authDomain: "",
            databaseURL: "",
            projectId: "",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: "",
            appId: "",
            measurementId: 
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        firebase.analytics();

        const booksRef = firebase.firestore().collection("JSDATA");
        var srno = 0;

        
 
         booksRef.get().then(function (querySnapshot){
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                    srno++;
                    document.getElementById("myTable1").getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + srno + "</td><td>" + doc.data().Email  + "</td> <td>" +  doc.data().Password + "</td></tr>";
                     // console.log(aa);
                       
                });
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#myTable1').DataTable();
                });
                
            });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Frestore Data</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>FireStore Data</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="data">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="myTable1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="th-sm" scope="col">Sr.No</th>
                    <th class="th-sm" scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th class="th-sm" scope="col">Password</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default a Firestore query is NOT sorted according to a specific field. If you want to sort (order by) by Email, you need to adapt your query as follows:

```
    const booksRef = firebase.firestore().collection("JSDATA").orderBy("Email");
     booksRef.get().then(function (querySnapshot){
```

More details in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data).

Note that "an `orderBy()` clause also filters for existence of the given field. The result set will not include documents that do not contain the given field."

Comment: i already try this but i don't want like that , i want like https://datatables.net/

Comment: This is much more complicated: either you use a Table library (but you need to download all the data if you want to paginate in the frontend) or you develop yourself the sorting and paginating function together with the corresponding queries. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Comment: ohh noo... in which used orderBy and i dont want to use it, i want like when i click on email tab then it is automatically sort like i sended  link..

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you wanna sort your table allowing the user to click on a head cell and them sort by that. If so, I did something similar like this:

```
getClientsPaginated({ companyId, order, limit = null, startAt = null, endAt = null, searchByTerm = null }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const query = (ref) => {
            if (searchByTerm) {
                ref = ref.where(order['field'], '==', searchByTerm);
            } else {
                ref = ref.orderBy(order['field'], order['direction']);
            }

            if (startAt) ref = ref.startAfter(startAt);
            if (endAt) ref = ref.endBefore(endAt);

            if (limit) {
                if (!endAt) {
                    ref = ref.limit(limit);
                } else {
                    ref = ref.limitToLast(limit);
                }
            }

            return ref;
        };

        this.db.collection('your_collection', query)
            .get().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((clients) => {
                <rest of your code here>
            });
    });
}
```

So the thing is, on click events on a header cell you fire your function that queries the database, passing an object with the parameters (in this case) like this:

```
const parameters = {
    companyId: companyId,
    order: queryOrder,
    limit: Number(limit),
    startAt: next,
    endAt: previous,
    searchByTerm: term
};

getClientsPaginated(parameters)
```

I hope this can be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Sorting in Firestore when fetching data this way-

```
booksRef.orderBy('the_fieldname_that_you_want_to_order_by').get()
// if you want to sort in decending order then
booksRef.orderBy('the_fieldname_that_you_want_to_order_by', 'desc').get()
```

Comment: Hi Nawaz, SO discourages code-only answers. I would be helpful if you would edit your answer with an explanation of how and why your solution works. Cheers!